# How to make a responsive reversed div with another div as a content with text

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a div, it is reversed and it has border-radius of 20%
I am wondering how can I make it responsible, best practice for this one. You can just tell me I will make it by myself.

I tried to show you the responsiveness I want to achieve.
Also, another question is how can I make inner div touch orange div's sides.

[image]

```
    div (orange block)
    .rotate {
        width: 130vh;
        height: 130%;
        background-color: white;
        transform: var(--rotate);
        border-radius: var(--border-radius);
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    content (red block)
    .rotateBlockContent {
        width: 95vh;
        height: 60%;
        border-radius: var(--border-radius);
        transform: rotate(-45deg); reversed since .rotate div is reversed
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
    }
```

I want to know how I can make it mobile-friendly because I did it with media queries and I have like 100500 media queries. It just hardcoded and doesn't work as I want it to be.
Maybe some of you know best practice, how to develop a good responsive design of this website or if you have some information about where I can check it out, please share.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it differently and use clip-path to simulate the rotated element:

```css
.box {
  background: orange;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}
.box::before,
.box::after {
  content:"";
  width:calc(100%/4);
}

.box>div {
  margin:calc(100%/4) 0;
  flex: 1;
  
  /* irrelevant styles */
  background: blue;
  color:#fff;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div> some content inside </div>
</div>
```

To keep the ratio you change the fixed height with a padding applied to pseudo elements:

```css
.box {
  background: orange;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}
.box::before,
.box::after {
  content:"";
  width:calc(100%/4);
  padding-top:100%;
}

.box>div {
  flex: 1;
  margin:calc(100%/4) 0;
  
  /* irrelevant styles */
  background: blue;
  color:#fff;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div> some content inside </div>
</div>
```

And if you want the radius, we add a small SVG filter:

```css
.box {
  background: orange;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}

.box::before,
.box::after {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100%/4);
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.box>div {
  flex: 1;
  margin: calc(100%/4) 0;
  
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="filter: url('#goo');">
  <div class="box">
    <div> some content inside </div>
  </div>
</div>


<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```